# I want to separate products based on id but tempatesyntaxterror is shown

Tags: django, templates

I tried this:

```
{% for i in object %} 
    {% if i.get(id=1) %}
        <img src="{{object.img1.url}}" />
        <p><b>Rs {{i.price}}</b></p>
    {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

But, this error is shown:

> TemplateSyntaxError
> Could not parse the remainder: '(id=1)' from 'i.get(id=1)'

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to get the *id* of `i` and trying it to check with if statement. So, try

```
{% for i in object %} 
    {% if i.id == 1 %}  <--- Here
        <img src="{{ i.img1.url }}" />   <--- Here also i.img1.url not object.img1.url
        <p><b>Rs {{i.price}}</b></p>
    {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: perhaps also point out that the `img src` is referring to the list of objects too, and not the current `i` ... At least that is my assumption based on the code provided!

Comment: i tried this  still shows the error:"TemplateSyntaxError
Could not parse the remainder: '==1' from '==1'"

Comment: Show the complete traceback